# Striped triangle in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to code a striped triangle in CSS, which will be a resize icon as you can normally find in the lower right of a window such as this one: [image]

I tried using repeating-linear-gradient and creating a triangle with the div-border trick, but I can't combine those, as the triangle is made from borders, and the gradient is for background.

So how do I get a div that looks like the image? I can't find anything helpful on google or here on stackoverflow.

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you've tried?

Comment: Have a look at linear gradients

Comment: No, sorry, I don't, because I have no idea of how to start this at all. I can do the stripes like here: https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/ and triangles like here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ but I can't combine those to look like the pic above...

Comment: I wouldn't make a triangle, if it is for the corner, then just make a square with horizontal stripes, rotate it 45 degress and put it in the corner (hiding the overflow of the parent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the links you provided to make this:

```css
#a {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #fff, #fff 2px, #000 2px, #000 3px);
  width: 20px; 
  height: 20px;
}

#b {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top: 25px solid #fff;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
<div id="b">
</div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can change the size of the div and the stripes to whatever you please.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for and couldn't get my mind around it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I would use box shadow on pseudo element to create 3 strips, and rotate it to bottom right corner

```css
.strip_tri {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.strip_tri::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px black, 0 17px 0 1px black, 0 24px 0 1px black;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.5);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="strip_tri"></div>
```

Comment: Broken snippet :) doesn't show in Safari

Comment: thanks, it seems safari had problem with 0.5px, i fixed it,

Comment: Works indeed, nice work.